# How to show a modal from an anchor in a checkbox label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web page with a form. I use Bootstrap and Jquery. In this form i have a checkbox (to check if agree terms and conditions). In the label of the checkbox i have something like "i want to agree terms". When someone clicks on the word "terms" i want a modal to show up with all the terms and conditions.

I tried to put the JavaScript code which opens the modal in the attribute `onclick` but it works only on desktop browser. All the mobile browsers do nothing.
The interesting fact is that if I put the anchor element before the  input element, it works. But if I put it after the input element, it doesn't work anymore.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <a class="terms" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#modalTerms').modal('show');">This works</a>

    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkTerms" name="checkTerms">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkTerms">I agree with <a class="terms" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#modalTerms').modal('show');>terms and conditions</a></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You missed a double quote after the onclick attribute on the a, tho I don't think that's the culprit

Comment: `The interesting fact is that if I put the anchor element before the input element, it works`. Inspect the element and check your input element is overlapping the anchor in mobile view.

Answer (score 3):

try using bootstrap `data-toggle` and `data-target` property

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using inline click event is not the issue, here is working code.
Also, you made mistake here, closing quotes for href attribute was missing.

```
href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#modalTerms').modal('show');>
```

You haven't added any modal code like solution below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
    <a class="terms" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#modalTerms').modal('show');">This works</a>

    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkTerms" name="checkTerms">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkTerms">I agree with <a class="terms" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#modalTerms').modal('show');">terms and conditions</a></label>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="modalTerms" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Checkbox is checked
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTerms" can be use without writing javascript